# Visual Studio Code Debug Bar

Tags: html, css, image, visual-studio-code, text

So I have no idea what I did but I was editing my code in VSC and must have pressed something because the next thing I knew is that (as shown in the picture down below here labeled "VSC SS1") is what happened when I clicked on Run And Debug in the side menu bar.

[Visual Studio Code SS 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pypc.png)

And I would like to get back to this menu as (shown below in the picture) but I have no idea how

[Visual Studio Code SS 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4AWl.png)

Comment: You have probably some folder under `.vscode` in your project files. Delete it and try again.

Comment: Thank you I will let you know if it works

Comment: try command `restore factory palettes`